# Windows service couldn't access a certificate store

Tags: windows, wcf, service, windows-services, truststore

I'm trying to authenticate to Opends server using winldap , I installed my self signed certificate to system trusted root certificates,personal store etc(where ever applicable). ldp.exe which is a tool by microsoft works fine for ssl and tls connection .I have 2 user accounts in my PC(admin and Administrator) everything works fine for both user accounts , except my windows service.

My windows service(a library management program) couldn't verify the server certificate. but my sample code works(which is a small part of code similar to my windows service) ,

I have seen similar scenarios on this website and their suggestion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx).

My service displays Group name as N/A in services tab and user name as SYSTEM in processes tab of task manager and I'm not sure what to do , please some one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Windows has 3 types of certificate stores Local User , System , Services .
Usually windows services run as a special account called System(we can make it run on a particular user account as well)

Self signed certificate is added to the local user account alone (for both admin and Administrator as mentioned). so the windows Service couldn't verify the certificate.

Solution is to add the certificate to the System store .

The program works fine

Comment: Where can I find the "System store" to add the certificate to it?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves did you find the solution?

Comment: @tryingToLearn no. I don’t remember how or if I solved this. It was in a previous company where I worked at ao I won’t be able to search the code either. Good luck bro.

Comment: It's an old thread. But what solved the problem for me was adding the certificate to local computer as shown in this link:
https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-import-certificates-into-the-ms-windows-local-machine-certificate-store/170504615105398/